# Add year-based dynamic dropdown to change results of Google Sheets query

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I use Google Sheets to keep track of the release schedule for my blog. Each new year I create a sheet which keeps track of the date, content type, title, and a few other items.

A year or so ago I created a "dashboard" page which aggregated data across each sheet and tallied up the results by author and content type. This is really helpful when looking at the data as a whole, but I'd like to also just look at the data by a single year; how many reviews were published in 2019? How many videos did we release in 2020, etc.

[image: Aggregate content type for all years]

I'd like to include a dynamic dropdown that I can change to *only* show results from the selected year, but that also includes an "all years" option as the default. Here's a sample of the data from one year:

```
Date                    Type        Title
Mon, January 11, 2021   Review      Beez
Wed, January 13, 2021   Review      Dragomino
Thu, January 14, 2021   Video       Meeple Land
Fri, January 15, 2021   Article     Year in Review - 2020
```

And here's the current query I'm using the power the screenshot above:

```
=query(
    {
        '2021'!D3:D337;
        '2020'!D3:D339;
        '2019'!D3:D271;
        '2018'!D3:D204;
        '2017'!D3:D140;
        '2016'!D3:D110;
        '2015'!D3:D5
    },
    "Select Col1, count(Col1) where Col1 is not null group by Col1 order by Col1 asc"
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Query function is a bit messy when it comes to data usage.
Look here: https://www.benlcollins.com/spreadsheets/query-dates/

What I propose is usage of a few simple formulas: unique, countif, year(), and if.

My solution with dummy data is available here:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rikdQa9UKKHNMAfVVCvVuommeaYQQZYHdhcOyaOnXGc/copy

It can be used with multiple ranges within {}

First you have to know what years are found on the list to make a dropdown list.
Also you need your default value: "All years"
I use unique formula and year formula to extract year from data:
={"All years";ArrayFormula(unique(year(B3:B10)))}

[image]

Then I go to menu and choose Data --> Data validation and declare F2:F15 as a list of values available. This will update whenever new year values will appear.
[image]

Then I list all the post types found in column C

[image]

Finally I count number of occurences of each type of post for a year chosen, or for all years if "All years" value is chosen.
[image]

You can use multiple ranges for each formula, but if dataset is not that big, you can make a separate sheet for all your ranges combined. This will take some more space, but will make addressing a lot easier.

Comment: Thank you for your thorough answer Krzysztof! Once I've got a bit of time I'll walk through it to see if it works for my needs. To answer your question my dataset is around 1100 entries right now, and will grow approximately 300-350 per year.

Comment: Krzysztof, thank you again for your recommendation. It took me a while to get my head around your suggestion but I got it working and it's a really slick system. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

add simple `IF`:

```
=QUERY({A2:C}, 
 "select Col2,count(Col2) 
  where "&IF(D1="all years", "Col2 is not null", "year(Col1) = "&D1)&" 
  group by Col2 
  label count(Col2)''")
```

[image]